# RecyclerView ItemClick transition

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I want to create a transition effect for RecyclerView something like,

https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_9/0B6Okdz75tqQsYkFhbTNWaHpydm8/patterns_navigational-transitions_parent-to-child_list-02_xhdpi_019.mp4

Like the parent-children transitions.

What kind of Animation I should create to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create something like android:transitionGroup  attribute in layout files and work with  shared element views

a nice example of this https://stories.uplabs.com/music-player-3a85864d6df7#.uwcuovwhz